# An adverb for all possibilities/possible options?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, meaning-in-context

I want an adverb for the following blank. The adverb is used when we want to say that the options/possibilities we are gonna talk about exhaust all options/possibilities.

> A and B are all the factors that are relevant to the problem X.
>   Therefore, ----- there are 3 possible ways to explain the problem X:
>   1) A causes it; 2) B causes it; and 3) A and B both cause it.

I remember that I saw somewhere the word *topologically*, or a word similar to that, was used in the sense mentioned above.*Topologically* has not such a sense according to the dictionaries I saw, and I couldn't find any word similar to it.

Comment: I suggest you use more than one word.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is "there are only 3 possible ways . . . "

Comment: I suggest that can't always be done but if you must have a single word, *exactly or *only* would sometimes work.

Comment: There are (ignoring the possibility that neither A nor B is causal) four possibilities: (a) A is a sufficient and necessary causal factor; B isn't. / (b) B is a sufficient and necessary causal factor; A isn't.  / (c) A is a sufficient and necessary causal factor; so is B. / (d) A and B together comprise a sufficient and necessary causal factor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The word I was looking for is *[typologically](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/typology)*

> **typology:** the systematic classification of the types of something according to their common characteristics
>   <sub>*definition from [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/typology)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

An old thread, I know, but worth adding to. You're trying to work with sets here, so you need to define a set of all possibilities. Having defined that set, you can then define its members. By using "consists" (e.g. "The set consists of..."), you can explicitly (and clearly) define all members of the set

You might want to try e.g. "Therefore, the set of all possible ways to explain the cause of problem X consists of: 1) A causes it; 2) B causes it; and 3) both A and B cause it."

Answer (score 1):

The adverb "*overall*" fills the blank  precisely.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/overall_2)) **overall**  including everything or everyone; in total

- Therefore, overall there are 3 possible ways…

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not topologically which means according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/topology):

> 1: topographic study of a particular place; specifically :the history
>   of a region as indicated by its topography 2 a (1) :a branch of
>   mathematics concerned with those properties of geometric
>   configurations (such as point sets) which are unaltered by elastic
>   deformations (such as a stretching or a twisting) that are
>   homeomorphisms (2) :the set of all open subsets of a topological space]

Words you might use are: "completely", "comprehensively", or perhaps best of all "exclusively."

> Therefore, there are exclusively 3 possible ways to explain the
>   problem X: 1) A causes it; 2) B causes it; and 3) A and B both cause
>   it.

Or another possibility is "exactly", in this specific context:

> Therefore, there are exactly 3 possible ways to explain the
>   problem X: 1) A causes it; 2) B causes it; and 3) A and B both cause
>   it.